# TYPO3 8.7: Custom field is not added into tt_content table from custom extension

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

i try to add one custom field into the tt_content table in a custom extension. I added Create table statement in ext_tables.sql and registerd the field in custom content element TCA.

But when i activate the extension, no extra field in tt_content is added.
Somenone could lead me to my error or give a hint where to look.

As i understood the documentation, the statements in ext_tables.sql are performed automatically by the extension manager when an extension gets activated.

System is TYPO3 8.7.17.

Absolut beginner in TYPO3. Thanks guys...

```
// ext_tables.sql
CREATE  TABLE tt_content (
 tx_ug_content_ext_tab_item int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
);

// content element TCA file
/***************
* Register fields
*/
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns'] = array_replace_recursive(
   $GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns'],
   [
       'tx_ug_content_ext_tab_item' => [
           'label' => 'LLL:EXT:ug_content/Resources/Private/Language/Backend.xlf:ext_tab_item',
           'config' => [
               'type' => 'inline',
               'foreign_table' => 'tx_ug_content_ext_tab_item',
               'foreign_field' => 'tt_content',
               'appearance' => [
                   'useSortable' => true,
                   'showSynchronizationLink' => true,
                   'showAllLocalizationLink' => true,
                   'showPossibleLocalizationRecords' => true,
                   'showRemovedLocalizationRecords' => false,
                   'expandSingle' => true,
                   'enabledControls' => [
                       'localize' => true,
                   ]
               ],
               'behaviour' => [
                   'mode' => 'select',
                   'localizeChildrenAtParentLocalization' => true,
               ]
           ]
       ]
   ]
);
```

Solution found, there are two spaces between CREATE and TABLE.
Error was found by Simon Gilli.

Answer (score 0):

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 3
```

Or in other words: Remove the comma after your field definition to avoid that SQL error.

Comment: You are right, thats not valid SQL syntax. But in TYPO3 you need the trailing comma due the  table already exists and TYPO3 extends the table with the new field.

The solution was 2 spaces between CREATE and TABLE.